# AJAX (NO jQuery) call to processForm.php doesn't return $_POST['email'] with responseText?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

### Answered

OK so I have it working now. Thanks to @ASK for the assist. There was just a few changes that needed to be made. A helpful resource for anyone else struggling with this was [Using FormData Objects - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

My first mistake came from a misunderstanding of what `e.preventDefault()` was doing. I thought it just stopped the page from redirecting to `processForm.php`. In fact it does, but also stops the form from submitting to `processForm.php` too. So when I was making my ajax call to `processForm.php` the reason my `$email` variable wasn't returning the submitted email was because there had been no submitted email yet. And when I turned of `e.preventDefault()` it worked for the opposite reason. Quite obvious in hindsight.

I've posted my working changes at the bottom here. I'm not sure why but I had to leave out `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` to get it working. So I still need to learn more about `setRequestHeader` to know what's going on there.

---

### **Original Question:**

So I've got this form that I send to `processForm.php` when submitted. I haven't got around to it yet but once sent, `processForm.php` will add the email to a database that will be used to serve a mailing list for a newsletter. Also note `processForm.php` will be used for another more complex contact form later.

What I'm trying to do right now is create the response message for the user.

After the user submits the form and the response from `processForm.php` is received a `<div>` will slide down from top of screen with the message, as shown in the below `php`.

I'm using **`JS`** *(NO jQuery)* to prevent the page redirect and AJAX to make the call to `processForm.php`. I get the responseText from `processForm.php`, but the `$email` is missing.

In the `js` if I comment out `e.preventDefault();`, allowing the page to redirect, `$email` is included in the `echo $response`. But with `e.preventDefault();` engaged it isn't.

I've tried heaps of different variations of the code below, including just echoing `$email`, placing `$email` inside the `$message` variable but nothing works. The email is always excluded from the `xhr.responseText`.

**Here's 2 screen shots of what's happening:**

**1)** This image is with `e.preventDefault();` called. *(i.e. using ajax)*
[image]

**2)** And here we see the response when `e.preventDefault();` is commented out. *(i.e. no ajax and redirected to `processForm.php`)*
[image]

Since I still receive the echoed `$response` when making the ajax call I know `processForm.php` is building its variables and running the `if` statement. But why isn't `$email` included in the `xhr.responseText`?

The other variables, `$message` and `$response` are returned so what's going on?

Am I using `$email = $_POST['email'];` correctly? *I think yes as it works with the redirect to `processForm.php.`*

**Here's the code.**
I know their are security steps like `htmlspecialchars` and `trim` that should be used, but right now I just want to get it up and running.

HTML:

```
<form id="mailing_list_form" action="processForm.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div id="their_email" class="their_email form_field">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="state_container form_field">
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <select name="state">
      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
      <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
      <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
      <option value="SA">SA</option>
      <option value="Tasmaina">Tasmaina</option>
      <option value="Victoria">Victoria</option>
      <option value="WA">WA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button id="form_trigger" type="submit" name="mList">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

  $mailingListForm = $_POST['mList'];

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];

  if(isset($mailingListForm)){
     $message = "has been added to the mailing list.";
     $response = '<h2 class="form_submitted_status">Succes!<i class="form_submitted_details">'.$email." ".$message.'</i></h2>';
     echo $response;
  }
?>
```

JS:

```
formTriggerClick();
function formTriggerClick(){
    var formTrigger = document.getElementById("form_trigger");

    formTrigger.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(formTrigger.hasAttribute("data-validation")){
        processForm();

        function processForm(){
            getResponse(function(result){
                var resultText = result;
                var response = document.getElementsByClassName("form_submitted")[0];
                response.innerHTML = resultText;
                response.setAttribute("data-show", "response");
            });

        }// processForm() -- END --//

        function getResponse(callback){
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if(xhr.status === 200) {
                        callback(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.open("POST", "processForm.php");
            xhr.send();
        }//getResponse() -- END --//

    }// if formTrigger has data-validation -- END --//
    });

}//formTriggerClick() // -- END --//
```

---

### **How is was solved:**

All I had to do was:

**1)** create this `var form` to hold the filled out form.
**2)** and initiate a new FormData object inside `send()`.
**3)** you'll note the `setRequestHeader` is commented out, I don't seem to need it.
***3.1)*** Still working out why...

```
function getResponse(callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    var form = document.getElementById("mailing_list_form");
    xhr.open("POST", "processForm.php");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(new FormData(form));
}//getResponse() -- END --//
```

And that's it. It all really boiled down to a misunderstanding of `e.preventDefault()`. And that I had used ajax previously to return a page and didn't need any of this *(but that was because I was just returning the page/doc as is and not trying to construct variable values out of dynamic, submitted data)*

Thanks to @ASK again for setting me straight.

Comment: Try declaring `xhr` as a local variable with `var xhr;`.

Comment: Where? Do you mean just before `xhr = new XMLHttpRequet();`. If so I did that, it didn't change anything.

Comment: see my edit in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that your form is submmiting.
I think your problem is this:

> You are using `form_trigger` in the function `formTriggerClick` in line 1

And as far as I know you don't have element with id `form_trigger` instead you have `trigger`

You full working solution will be like this:

```
formTriggerClick();
function formTriggerClick(){
    var formTrigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
    ...
```

**Edit 1**

Next problem you never send the value to the `proccessForm.php`.
Here is how you do something like that:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("field1Name=value1&field2Name=value2&...");
```

See this for more details about AJAX http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

**Edit 2**

And you initialize `xhr` like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**Edit 3**
Heres how you send the data(However works for IE 10 and above):

```
var form = document.getElementById("formId");
var data = new FormData(form);
xrh.send(data);
```

For IE < 10:

```
var emailValue= document.getElementById("emailFieldId").value;
....
var data="email="+emailValue+"...so on";
xhr.send(data);
```

Here's a [good example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml).

You could always use some functions. And that's when `jQuery` is very handy.

Comment: No that was just a mistake in my markup here. Thanks for spotting though, I've corrected it now.

Comment: What do you mean? The values of the email and state `input`'s. Yes they are sent to `processForm.php` because if you turn off `e.preventDefault();` and allow the page the redirect the value/s are echoed out in `$response`.

Comment: yeah because they are handled by the form element no your `ajax` code

Comment: you need to pass the values yourself in `ajax`

Comment: so I recommend `jQuery` for `ajax`.. but this also works fine.

Comment: Ok, so I though because I echo `$response` in `processForm.php` the `xhr.responseText` would include the `$email`. Could explain how the string in `send()` works a little more, or direct me to some good articles. How would I return the submitted email? `"email=email"` would just return the string email.